# Firestore delete non-existent ancestor documents and sub-collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to clean my collection data. I have the collection name **"teams"**. It has data and *sub-collection* name **"players"**.

I have deleted **"teams"** document by simple delete query of Firestore but as we know we can't delete sub-collection *(players)* by deleting main/ancestor docID. We must have to fetch all the documents from **"players"** collection and then delete them first.
After we should delete the ancestor *(teams' doc)* document so it will be clear all for the collection.

It's not possible to fetch those orphaned documents from **"teams"** collection. so what is the way to clean these documents from the collection?

[image: I want to delete all the document (italic)]

> ~ PS: I have created a firebase cloud function to delete sub-collections documents while deleting the ancestor doc.

```
exports.deleteOrphanedTeamsDoc = functions.firestore
  .document('teams/{teamID}')
  .onDelete(async (snap, context) => {
    var teamID = context.params.teamID;
    console.log("Deleted teamID --->>> " + teamID);

    const store = admin.firestore();
    var teamsPlayer = await store.collection('teams').doc(teamID).collection('players').get()

    teamsPlayer.docs.forEach(async(val) => {
      await store.collection('teams').doc(teamID).collection('players').doc(val.id).delete();
    });
  });
```

So with the help of the above code, I can delete fresh teams docID with sub-collections too.

But what about all the orphaned docs that available in my **"teams"** collection.

> **Update 1:**

I tried the code of **Renaud Tarnec**, Sorry but I am new to function so not many ideas for it. I clicked on the **run** button but getting some issues

[image]

```
6:46:13.625 pm
scheduledFunction
Function execution took 12608 ms, finished with status: 'error'
6:46:13.622 pm
scheduledFunction
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
6:46:13.622 pm
scheduledFunction
at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
6:46:13.622 pm
scheduledFunction
at /workspace/index.js:161:53
6:46:13.622 pm
scheduledFunction
ReferenceError: promises is not defined 
6:46:01.018 pm
scheduledFunction
Function execution started
```

I think issues is here `ReferenceError: promises is not defined` at

```
const parentsSnapshotsArray = await Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: So you basically want to delete those *italic* documents?

Comment: Exactly - But the issue is we can't able to fetch it by the simple query.

Comment: I understand that you also want to delete the players docs as well, is that right?

Comment: Yes I want to delete all the stuff of particular document of teams colelction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But what about all the orphaned docs that available in my "teams"
> collection.

As you mentioned, your Cloud Function will not be triggered for the `teams` documents that were already deleted.

What you could do to delete the orphan `player` docs is to run a scheduled Cloud Function every X minutes/hours.

The following Cloud Function uses a [CollectionGroup query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) to get all the `player` docs and delete them. Note that you need to have a Firestore index for the query. Note also how we use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) in order to return a unique Promise when all the asynchronous work is done; this is key to [correctly manage the lifecycle of your Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun((context) => {

    const playersRef = admin.firestore().collectionGroup('players');
    const playersSnap = await playersRef.get();

    const promises = [];
    playersSnap.forEach((doc) => {
        promises.push(doc.ref.delete());
    });
    return Promise.all(promises)

});
```

Now, we need to add an extra business logic. The `player` docs shall be deleted **only if the parent `team` doc does not exist**.

The following code should do the trick (**untested**):

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun(async (context) => {

    const playersRef = admin.firestore().collectionGroup('players');
    const playersSnap = await playersRef.get();

    const docParentIdsToDelete = [];

    const docParentIdsTreated = [];
    const promisesParentDocs = [];
    playersSnap.forEach((doc) => {
        const parentTeamRef = doc.ref.parent.parent;
        const parentTeamId = parentTeamRef.id;
        if (docParentIdsTreated.indexOf(parentTeamId) < 0) {
            // We need to check if the parent exists
            promisesParentDocs.push(parentTeamRef.get());
            docParentIdsTreated.push(parentTeamId);
        }
    });

    const parentsSnapshotsArray = await Promise.all(promisesParentDocs);

    parentsSnapshotsArray.forEach(snap => {
        if (!snap.exists) {
            // The parent team doc DOES NOT exist. It is shown in italic in the Firebase console.
            // => We need to delete the players child docs
            docParentIdsToDelete.push(snap.id);
        }
    });
    
    const promisesDeletion = [];
    playersSnap.forEach((doc) => {
        const parentTeamId = doc.ref.parent.parent.id;
        if (docParentIdsToDelete.indexOf(parentTeamId) > -1) {
            // We need to delete the player doc
            promisesDeletion.push(doc.ref.delete());
        }
    });
    
    return Promise.all(promisesDeletion);
    
});
```

Basically, we first get all the `player` docs. Then we loop to check if the parent `team` doc exists or not (using an array to minimize the number of queries). If it does not exist we push its ID to an array => the `player` child docs need to be deleted. Then we loop again on the `player` docs and we delete the desired ones (again by pushing the deletion promises to an Array which is passed to `Promise.all()`). There might be some room for optimizing the code and reduce the number of loops but the logic is there (If I didn't do any mistake :-)).

Comment: PS: Note that it is not a good idea to use async/await within a forEach loop as you did in your question. See [here](https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404) and [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop). You should use `Promise.all()` as shown in the anwser.

Comment: Really Impressive information, Let me play with your code/suggestion. Will get back to you soon. Anyways thanks for this information.

Comment: I just did copy and paste the above code and run click on the "run" button but not help to delete those docs. Sorry but I am a little bit new for function.

Comment: Which "run" button? Can you show a screenshot?

Comment: If you follow the deployment instructions [get started doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?authuser=0#deploy-functions-to-a-production-environment), this Cloud Function shall run automatically every 5 minutes.

Comment: I have updated my question with your suggestion, Please check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234163/discussion-between-ipatel-and-renaud-tarnec).

Answer (score 2):

The Firebase Console is indicating through those *italic* documents that, those documents actually don't exist. Those documents don't exist either because you didn't create them or you deleted them explicitly. So those documents are still displayed because there is a sub-collection beneath them. So basically the ID of the document is somehow reserved if you need to do some operations in the future.

One thing to remember, in Cloud Firestore documents and subcollections don't work like filesystem files and directories. So in conclusion, you cannot delete something that doesn't exist. In other words, because there is no physical document at that location so you cannot perform a delete operation.

Comment: Yep - Thanks for your response. I spent lots of time and everywhere telling the same things. But is there no any script or any firebas- could-function related stuff that useful in my case? So what I have to manually delete all those docIDs ?

Comment: No, there is not. As long as a subcollection exists in a document, that document will be displayed in *italic*. You cannot change that. If you aren't comfortable seeing those documents in italic, then you should consider creating those subcollections as top-level collections, if it's possible in your project. Otherwise, delete all documents from the subcollection and those documents will disappear automatically.

Comment: Absolutely, Thanks for more clarification.

Comment: Hey - just wanted to know that `Renaud Tarnec`'s and is working perfectly.

Comment: As it deletes all documents under "players" subcollection, right? In that way, there will be no team document left. That's the point?